# buttons inside listview don't work properly?

Tags: android, xml, listview

in my list_item I have two buttons inside each item. the problem is that the buttons don't work unless I click the item then click the buttons.
Here for example I have to click on the item then click on the delete icon to delete the item.
[ListView with two items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy1na.png)

list_item :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_circle_black_24dp"
            android:tint="#4CAF50"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
            android:tint="#FF0000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think It's a problem of something like focusability in listview and it's items but I don't know how to fix it :D

Comment: have you remove that item from list after click button. or refresh the list to see the change?

Comment: show your item delete code here

Comment: add your adapter code. Use RecyclerView instead of ListView.

Comment: add your adapter code and listview code.

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: Everyone is going nuts about the adapter code ! quick post it before something happens :p

Comment: R you using any animation while loading the listview item?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone for lateness!

I've got the solution; the problem was that I deleting the ListView item in the Activity instead of doing it in the Adapter ;)

the Code that doesn't work (MainActivity) :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {


                // delete button
                ImageView deleteBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
                deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        mAdapter.remove(mAdapter.getItem(i));
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

The correct code (Adapter) :

```
 deleteBtn.setTag(position);
        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Integer index = (Integer) deleteBtn.getTag();
                remove(getItem(index));

            }
        });
```

Thank you so much everyone for helping :)